# Fading In and out inline div's without changing the position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The question might be a little bit confusing.

I have an inline div and the first one is meant to be a close/delete button. I'm trying to fadeIn the close button on hover, although when it's faded out the rest div's move to the left.

How would you prevent this?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x2SEv/

Hover on top of **'Some text goes here'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery functions `.show()` and `.hide()`, use the CSS attribute `display`.

When attribute display is set to none, the space filled by HTML element which is hidden is remove. So your second div move to left.

You have to use the CSS attribute `visibility`. It does the same thing that `display`, but it keeps the space filled by HTML.

Let's try :

In your JS :

```
$(".todo").mouseover(function() {
        $('.closebtn').css("visibility", "visible");
    });
    $(".todo").mouseout(function() {
        $('.closebtn').css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```

And your CSS :

```
.closebtn, .actions{visibility:hidden;}
```

Comment: Ah now I understood the functions .show() and .hide()... Thank you. I will be setting the position to absolute because there's alot of code to change

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to absolutely position the element that you're fading, and move your text in a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/x2SEv/1/ .

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
.div-to-fade {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0; top:0;
}
```

Comment: I don't advise using absolute position in this case. Because, HTML element which are `absolute`, are difficult to maintain, if you want an app compatible with all the most used browsers, with browser resizing, or with zoom level changes